# Moq Verify fails

Tags: c#, moq

I know this question was asked too many times here but I still cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.

I have a class implementing singleton. The class uses a web service proxy to access data. The data is cached and 2 subsequent calls should result in a single call to the service. It actually works, I can see it when stepping through, but the test fails.

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    Mock<IAtomService> atomService = new Mock<IAtomService>();
    atomService.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<List<Identifier>>(), It.IsAny<AtomReturnFormat>()))
               .Returns<List<Identifier>, AtomReturnFormat>(
                   (list, format) => new AtomList { Atoms = new AtomCollection(list.Select(ident => new Atom { ID = Guid.Parse(ident.ID) })) });

    AtomCache.Instance.AtomService = atomService.Object;

    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
    List<string> ids = new List<string> { id.ToString() };

    AtomCache cache1 = AtomCache.Instance;
    cache1.Get(ids);

    AtomCache cache2 = AtomCache.Instance;
    cache2.Get(ids);

    AtomService.Verify(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<List<Identifier>>(), It.IsAny<AtomReturnFormat>()), Times.Once());
}
```

The error is

```
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.Get(It.IsAny<List`1>(), It.IsAny<AtomReturnFormat>())

Configured setups:
x => x.Get(It.IsAny<List`1>(), It.IsAny<AtomReturnFormat>()), Times.Never
No invocations performed.
```

Any help is very appreciated

**Update**

```
    public List<Atom> Get(List<string> atomIds)
    {
        if (atomIds == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("atomIds");

        Dictionary<string, Atom> cachedAtoms = Cache.Get(atomIds.Where(id => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)).Distinct().ToList());

        List<Atom> atoms = new List<Atom>();
        if (cachedAtoms != null)
        {
            List<string> missingAtomIds = atomIds.Except(cachedAtoms.Keys).ToList();
            atoms.AddRange(getMissingAtoms(missingAtomIds));

            atoms.AddRange(cachedAtoms.Where(kv => kv.Value != null).Select(kv => kv.Value));
        }
        return atoms;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Atom> getMissingAtoms(List<string> atomIds)
    {
        if (atomIds == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("atomIds");

        List<Atom> atoms = new List<Atom>();
        if (atomIds.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Atom> list = retrieveAtoms(atomIds);
            Cache.Add(list);
            atoms.AddRange(list);
        }

        return atoms;
    }

    private List<Atom> retrieveAtoms(List<string> atomIDs)
    {
        if (atomIDs == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("atomIDs");

        if (AtomService == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("AtomCache: Atom Service proxy is not initialized.");

        Guid temp;
        List<Identifier> idList = atomIDs.Where(id => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) && Guid.TryParse(id, out temp))
                                         .Select(id => new Identifier {ID = id, Type = IdentifierTypeEnum.AtomPrimary})
                                         .ToList();

        List<Atom> atoms = atomIDs.Count == 0
                               ? new List<Atom>()
                               : ((AtomList) AtomService.Get(idList, AtomReturnFormat.Complete)).Atoms.ToList();

        return atoms;
    }
```

Comment: Can you also add the method you are testing please

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something changed in your update, I think you're this is the problem.

In your setup, you tell the mock what to return if a list of Identifiers are passed to it:

`atomService.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<List<Identifier>>(), %<--snip--`

However when you call, you're passing a list of strings:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string> { id.ToString() };

AtomCache cache1 = AtomCache.Instance;
cache1.Get(ids);
```

And I don't see anywhere that this list of strings is converted to a list of identifiers, so the mock never meets your setup condition, which is: when asked for any list of Identifiers, and therefore it properly reports it was asked 0 times.

Comment: hmmm I pass List<Identifier> to AtomService.Get. it is created in the retrieveAtoms method:      List<Identifier> idList = atomIDs.Where(id => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) && Guid.TryParse(id, out temp))
                                         .Select(id => new Identifier {ID = id, Type = IdentifierTypeEnum.AtomPrimary})
                                         .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem. It was a different instance of the mock that I called Verify on. when I copied the code in here, I simplified the code and it fixed the error :)

thank you